# My battery is saying fully charged but will still take charge does that mean my battery is going bad

Tags: battery

Have tested battery an it reads fully charged but when I put a battery charger on it it still takes a charge . What could be wrong

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Older batteries increase in leakage current at full CV and also your CV may be set too high. This is a common  sign of battery aging Actual charge rate and battery specs can be more specific

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong. You can always pass a current "backwards" through a battery if you connect a higher voltage across the terminals.

If the battery is fully charged and you force a *high current* "backwards" through it, you will heat it up, produce potentially explosive gas, and evaporate some of the liquid inside it, but a battery charger won't cause that sort of damage unless the charger itself is faulty.

Comment: I'd have to caution you on what you're saying here. A "non-smart" charger (which there are plenty of them out there), can and will boil a battery. Even if you have it on a 2A setting, it can still cause issues. It's not good to leave a battery charger on a battery for an extended period of time *after the battery is fully charged*. It can cause issues. There are such things as battery *maintainers* which will do the job without issue, but I would never trust a charger past when the battery is to the full mark.